# Transaction Management between two war files in Java

Tags: java, spring, web, transactions, jta

I am using Spring "WebSphereUowTransactionManager" for transaction management. 
But I am not sure about its capability for transaction managemnt between two war files in a scenario like in which a transaction spans across two war files and this transaction manager is capable of handling commits,rollback etc.

Not sure really is it possible in Spring Transaction Management!

Any suggesstion or help will be highly appreciated !!

Comment: Have you got this two war's joined in one ear?

Comment: Ok thanks JakubK !! Now I have two separate wars without EAR . I will try with EAR.

Answer (score 1):

If you will pack those two war's into one ear you can define transaction manager in parent Spring context, and make your two war contexts extends it (by using beanRefContext). It will allow sharing beans between contexts as well as your transaction manager.